# to which extend we can use the data of healthsite.io - can we use maps etc. too?

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap, python

to which extend we can use the data of healthsite.io

**update:**: well i guess that it is evident:

since the data in Healthsites.io are indeed under the ODBL licence: https://github.com/healthsites/healthsites/wiki/Data
one can therefore indeed reuse the data he keeps the same licence and attribution.

in othher words: healthsites.io uses OpenStreet Map data and per ODbL,  every one is free to use this data in whatever way so far as he does attribute OpenStreetMap Contributors.  we can find out about OSM copyright here https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright

Healthsites.io is a very interesting project which takes the collaboratively gathered data to a new level The latest project features along with cutting-edge use cases.

question:  To which extend i can use the data of healthsites.io - can i use the maps too?
can we use the data-extracts and the Maps too!?

are they released under the: Open Data License (ODBL)

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Global_Healthsites_Mapping_Project

https://github.com/healthsites/healthsites/wiki/healthsites.io-license

[image]

**guess**: Since the data is released under Open Data License (ODBL), have a look at the TLDR Legal for ODBL. 
**that said**: it seems like  we can use the data since it indeed fits the conditions of the license.

**gueess that we can use:**

- Data extracts per country are available on Healthsites.io, which can be found by going to the map page and browsing the country list on the left panel. Clicking on the name of any country listed will show a dashboard for that country which includes a link for downloading the associated data as a shapefile.
- can we use the data-extracts and the Maps too!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question!

The data license is the same as the ODbL of OpenStreetMap.

﻿## ODC Open Database License (ODbL)

#### Preamble

The Open Database License (ODbL) is a license agreement intended to
allow users to freely share, modify, and use this Database while
maintaining this same freedom for others. Many databases are covered by
copyright, and therefore this document licenses these rights. Some
jurisdictions, mainly in the European Union, have specific rights that
cover databases, and so the ODbL addresses these rights, too. Finally,
the ODbL is also an agreement in contract for users of this Database to
act in certain ways in return for accessing this Database.

https://healthsites.io/map

[image]

Comment: great answer @mangamonk